# Way to have SQL intellisense or autocompletion inside code strings in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

In JetBrains IDE's like [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) this is a built-in feature. E.g. in the code below, editing the SQL inside the string would autocomplete as SQL and suggest table/column names from an active database connection.

```php
query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 50");
```

When using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or similar editors like [Theia](https://theia-ide.org/), this functionality would be supplied by a plugin. Unfortunately, I haven't come across a plugin on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) that has this feature. Some have autocomplete for `.sql` files, but not inline SQL. It's hard to believe this isn't possible yet in such a popular editor.

**Has anyone found a solution for this?**

Plugins I've tried so far (I'm specifically looking for Postgres):

- [SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools)
- [PostgreSQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ckolkman.vscode-postgres) - privately maintained
- [PostgreSQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-ossdata.vscode-postgresql) - abandonware by Microsoft

Comment: filed an issue here https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2291

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've found is the [Inline SQL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qufiwefefwoyn.inline-sql-syntax). It uses a connection to a db to lint inline SQL and it supports postgres.

It doesn't seem to support intellisense, but it is [open source](https://github.com/barklan/inline_sql_syntax) under an MIT license if you'd like to extend it or use it for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.vscode-sql-formatter). Supports Python, Go, Rust, JS, TS, Ruby, Java, C# and PHP.

Comment: It doesn't look like this extension does autocomplete, only formatting. The question asks for an extension that "suggests table/column names from an active database connection".

Answer (score 0):

You can by using the [SQL Server (mssql)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql) VS Code extension. The extension gives IntelliSense for SQL within JavaScript and TypeScript files. You just need to establish a connection to your database, and you should get inline SQL autocomplete and suggestions.

Comment: This looks relevant to some, but only supports a few SQL flavors: "An extension for developing Microsoft SQL Server, Azure SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse".

Answer (score 0):

I use it on Visual Studio and it works well, but Github Copilot works well. You have to pay for it unfortunately, but it's probably the best intellisence I've seen.

Comment: Copilot can provide SQL recommendations, but it's not schema-aware as far as I know and doesn't lint. So bugs are to be expected.